# How to enlarge the size (width and height) of individual slides or all the presentation?

Tags: beamer

I consider slides of beamer presentation to be small compared to the content I need to fit in into the slides.

Is there a clean way to add some inches/centimeters to a number of selected slides or maybe apply the change to all the slides of the presentation?

THanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short TeX code and mark in the resulting PDF what you want to change?

Comment: Have you considered using the `plain` option for slides where you need a bit of extra room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Disclaimer:

It is usually not a good idea to add too much information to a single slide. This risks overwhelming your audience. Use the following solution at your own risk, I definitely do not recommend it.

---

That being said, beamer offers the `shrink` option to fit more content on individual frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{normal frame}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=12]
  \frametitle{With shrink}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the default value for the option shrink?

Comment: @marcnicole There is no default value. Beamer will first typeset the frame normally, check of much more space is needed and then shrink as much as needed. However you want to set the minimal shrink percentage to something close to the necessary shrinkage or you will get empty space at the end of lines.