# Width of tcolorbox and resizebox. Prevent boxes to appear in line

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, width, textwidth

As soon as I use resizebox around a few tcolorbox, they all appear in the same line. I want to create a nice layout, with linebreaks, between some of these tcolorboxes, and then just shrink it to fit in my slide. I cannot do it without resizebox (or similar) because my tcolorboxes contain \huge and other \fontsizes in the same text that are already formatted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\shortlipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inline tcolorboxes Issue}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm]
        {\tiny \lipsum[1]}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm ]
        {\tiny \lipsum[1]}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    % FORCE A LINE BREAK
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm ]
        {\large\shortlipsum}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    % FORCE A LINE BREAK
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm ]
        {\Huge\shortlipsum}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any comment is much appreciated

Comment: Using resizebox for elements which contain text is usually not a good idea.

Comment: If I try your code without resizebox, it nicely fits in the frame.

Comment: I have put more text to make it not fit. But this is a minimal example. I would just like to enforce those linebreaks

Comment: Theoretically something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714013/36296 would work, but it would be better to choose suitable font sizes instead. As you are already using tcolorboxes, you could use its fitting library

Comment: `\resizebox` is like `\mbox` so always one line. Avoid using it,. but if you must you need to do it around each tcolorbox separately would be better to use \scalebox so you can scale them all by the smae amount but why foces the tcolorbox to 10cm then scale to \textwidth why not just set \textwidth as the width?

Comment: tcolorbox normally works in vmode and \resizebox puts you into hmode.  Try puttiing the tcolorboxes inside a minipage,

Answer (score 4):

[Scaling elements which contain text is usually a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296). Instead you should choose a suitable font size. As you are already using tcolorboxes, you could use the fitting library to choose suitable font sizes for you.

If you really want to scale your poor boxes, you could use the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714013/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\shortlipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=66]
\frametitle{Inline tcolorboxes Issue}

%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm]
        {\tiny \lipsum[1]}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm ]
        {\tiny \lipsum[1]}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    % FORCE A LINE BREAK
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm ]
        {\large\shortlipsum}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    % FORCE A LINE BREAK
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm ]
        {\Huge\shortlipsum}
    \end{tcolorbox}
%}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is good. But in this solution all the boxes appear stack vertically.

Comment: I am trying with this solution and the scalebox suggestion. But to change the font sizes now is really a lot of work in my real boxes (they have a large mix of font sizes inside )

Comment: @Albercoc If you use a `tcolorbox` (as opposed to a `\tcbox`) it will add line breaks before and after. This can bet switched off, but is completely unrelated to scaling them.

Comment: "they have a large mix of font sizes inside " That's why I suggested the tcolorbox fitting library. It can deal with a mixture of sizes.

Comment: @Albercoc ... also if you want to arrange your tcolorboxes in certain way, using a `tcbraster` is usually easier than doing this manually with line breaks etc.

Comment: Thank you really. I checked the fitting library, but my poor tcolorboxes have around 15 options. Most of which were added by chatgpt. I tried, naively, to transform tcolorbox to tcboxfit following your suggestion and removing some options that the documentation of the fitting package mentioned would not work, but it gives error. Tried a couple of things. But most of this code is in several interconnected \newcommands with up to 4 arguments and impossible to debug for me. It is a mess I know. The suggestion of \scalebox around each box is working though. Thank you all!